# Is there a need to use StyleSheet.create?

Tags: react-native

I am defining styles in this manner:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {},
    tabContent: {
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        flexDirection: "column",
        padding: 21
    },
    tabHeader: {
        flex: 0,
        fontSize: 10,
        paddingTop: 10,
    },
    tabText: {
        flex: 0,
        fontSize: 14,
        paddingTop: 10,
        textAlign: "left"
    },
})
```

However, one time I forgot to use StyleSheet.create and used a plain object:

```
const styles = {
    container: {},
    tabContent: {
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        flexDirection: "column",
        padding: 21
    },
    tabHeader: {
        flex: 0,
        fontSize: 20,
        paddingTop: 10,
    },
    tabText: {
        flex: 0,
        fontSize: 14,
        paddingTop: 10,
        textAlign: "left"
    },
}
```

Surprisingly it worked. 
Is there a need to use StyleSheet.create to define styles or can one use plain objects?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I *think* its still better to use `StyleSheet` where possible as its more performant than using regular objects.

From React Native Docs:

> Performance:
>
> - Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.
> - It also allows to send the style only once through the bridge. All subsequent uses are going to refer an id (not implemented yet).

Remember seeing something somewhere (think it was a github issue) with a similar question and someone saying it's still better to use `StyleSheet` for performance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I also noticed that regular objects won't throw errors. If you do { cursor: 'pointer' }, in a regular object, no error is thrown. If you do it in StyleSheet, it catches the error.

Comment: Note that is you attempt to _read_ a style object yourself, you'll need to use `flatten()` first if it was created by `StyleSheet.create()`. This negates the performance benefit and should be used only where necessary.

Comment: David could probably enhance his confidence level expressed in his answer; it's exactly right. `StyleSheet.create()` is purely a performance optimization, which certainly matters.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but FWIW

There is a difference. You can't concat (spread or assign) styles from `StyleSheet.create` because `react-native` throws.

Looks like `StyleSheet.create` returns anything but not a JS object. If you try to concat two styles from `StyleSheet.create`, `react-native` will produce you RebBox.

Example:

```
const css = StyleSheet.create( {
   btn: { color: 'blue' },
   mb10: { marginBottom: 10 }
} )

render() {
    // I want to concat styles using spread or assign
    let btnClass = { ...css.btn, ...css.mb10 }; // spread
    let btnClass = Object.assign({},css.btn, css.mb10); // plain'ol assign

    return (
        <Button style={btnClass} />
    )
}
```

But `react-native` suddenly throws `TypeError`. Styles from `StyleSheet.create` aren't objects for some reason.

> TypeError: in this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object...

[image]

Comment: The `style prop` does take an array of styles as argument. Not sure about its internals, but it works similar to object spread.

Answer (score -1):

Unless @David is referring to something that goes on during compilation, I believe the documentation here

> Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to
>   it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.

is referring to manually adding `style={{ ... }}` in your tags.

It's pretty easy to avoid re-using style objects, even across files, by simply importing style objects into arbitrary component files.

Personally, I prefer to use plain objects so I can compose style objects, like `style={Object.assign({}, style1, { color })}` something you can't do with `StyleSheet`

Comment: You can compose StyleSheet entries, it's `style={[styles.styleOne, styles.styleTwo]}`

Answer (score -2):

The wrong way is different.

Use `StyleSheet.create`, your will get red screen error tip:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    fontSize:"20",//error
 }
});
```

No use `StyleSheet.create`, you will get warn:

```js
const styles = {
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    fontSize: "20", //error
  }
};
```